# «В Керчи, на улице Самокиша...» Нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения, обстоятельство

Сначала город, потом улица — как уточнение. Стоит ли ставить запятую?

Comment: Ну-у... Мне кажется, что в Керчи нет улицы Самокиша. https://geodzen.com/ua/kerch/streets/%D1%81 Подберите, пожалуйста, другую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.
**1.** Уточняющие обстоятельства места: *В Крыму, **в Мисхоре,** прошлым летом я сделал изумительное открытие* (Купр.)...

К уточняющим обстоятельствам относятся названия районов, областей и т. п., обозначающие местонахождение поселков, деревень и т. д., а также указания в адресах...

В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.:
***Далеко в лесу** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится в лесу). — *Далеко, **в лесу,** раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится вне леса)...

Так что без контекста однозначно сказать, нужна запятая или нет, невозможно.

Без запятых:
Я вспомнил их первую совместную выставку в марте 1968 года **в Москве на улице Горького** в выставочном зале Союза художников. [В. И. Севастьянов. Дневник над облаками (1975)]
Особняк Горького **в Москве на улице Качалова** и дом его детства в городе Горьком… [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

С запятыми:
Вечером ― ресторан «Петербургские тайны»; появился такой **в Москве, на улице Обуха,** за Курским вокзалом, в переулке; позвали на открытие. [А. Б. Гребнев. Дневник (1997)]
Когда я жил **в Москве, на улице Мархлевского,** Глазков приходил ко мне очень часто, искал обычно партнера по шахматам... [Давид Самойлов. Общий дневник (1977-1989)]

[Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=117#pp117)